# Appending type data inline

Tags: raml

In my use case I have a RAML 1.0 library created by our R&D department that contains definition of multiple data types. Those data types are defined in a generic, parametrized manner so when I reference them in my RAML I do so using following syntax:

```
type: { resourceTypes.collectionWithCriteria: {itemName: reward, itemCriteria: types.RewardCriteria, itemType : types.RewardList} }
```

This generates proper GET request with query string defined by `types.RewardCriteria` and response defined by `types.RewardList`. It also generates the description for the GET resource defined as: `Retrieves the list of <<itemName | !pluralize>>`, which ends up being `Retrieves the list of rewards`.

In my RAML I would like to append additional description to my GET resource, however I 'd rather avoid overwriting library-generated one. Is that possible? I've already tried inline description and using overlay file, both of which simply replace description from the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot append for a single value simple property.

The [merging rules for traits / resource types](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#algorithm-of-merging-traits-and-methods) state that the description will be replaced:

> Every explicit node wins over the ones that are declared in a resource
>   type or trait. The rest are simply merged.

Also, the [merging rules of overlays and extensions](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#merging-rules) states that:.

> If the property is a Simple Property
>     If the property is a Single-value Simple Property, 
>          The property value in the identically named Current Target Tree Object property is **replaced** with its value from Current Extension Tree Object property.